# Text view is not show in LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I experience kind of weird behavior of placing Text view in nested ForEach in one LazyVGrid view. My code look like this

```
LazyVGrid(columns: dataColumns) {
    ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
        Text("\(dateFormatter.string(from: month))")
    }
    ForEach(categories) { category in
        ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
            Text("aaa")
        }
    }
}
```

and "aaa" string is not shown but if I add just another Text view like this

```
ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
    Text("aaa")
    Text("bbb")
}
```

then both Text views with strings are repeatedly shown as expected. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is to do with view identity. `LazyVGrid` uses each views identity to know when they need to be loaded in.

Structural identity is also used by `SwiftUI` to identify views based on the structure of their view hierarchy. This is why when you added another view to the `ForEach` instance the views show, as they now are uniquely structurally identifiable from the other `ForEach` content.

Here, you have two separate `ForEach` instances inside the `LazyVGrid` which use the same identifiers. Two of the `forEach` instances are using `months` with the `id` `\.self` to identify them. These are conflicting and should be unique to avoid these sorts of issues.

To fix this you should preferably use a unique array of elements for each `ForEach` instance, though could create a copy of the `months` array to use in the second `ForEach` instead of referring to the same instances. Here's an example:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MyType: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()

    var name = "Tester"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    var months: [MyType] = []
    var monthsCopy: [MyType] = []

    private var monthValues: [MyType] {
        [MyType()]
    }

    init() {
        months = monthValues
        monthsCopy = monthValues
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(months) { _ in
                Text("Test1")
                Text("Test2")
            }

            ForEach(monthsCopy) { _ in
                Text("Test3")
                Text("Test4")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If you replace `ForEach(monthsCopy)` with `ForEach(months)` you will see the issue you were faced with.